# In how many ways can the entries of a $3 \times 3$ table be filled in with $0$s and $1$s so that the sum of numbers in at least one row equals $0$?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can the entries of a $3 \times 3$ table be filled in with the numbers zero and one so that the sum of numbers in at least one of the rows is equal to zero?

Comment: Yes: you can put zero in all of them, for instance.

Comment: "so that the sum of numbers" so that the sum of numbers does what? If you fill them all with $1$ you can avoid this.  If you fill the first row with $0$ you can do this.  What actually is the question?

Comment: For the sum of a row to add up to zero all the  houses must be $0$.  I dont see any reason why filling a row with all $0$s would be at all difficult.  Just let the first row be $0$ and the rest can be any combination you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Use inclusion-exclusion over the sets $A_1,A_2,A_3$ where $A_i$ is the set "*The ways to fill a $3\times 3$ table with $0$'s and $1$'s such that the sum of the numbers in the $i$'th row is zero.*"

You are (*presumably after correcting your grammar*) trying to calculate $|A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3|$

Additional hint:

> Inclusion-exclusion implies $|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$

Additional hint:

> If the sum of the first row is zero, then every entry in the first row is zero.  Then in counting how many ways we can fill the rest of the table, we have $2$ options for the secondrow-firstcolumn entry, $2$ options for the secondrow-secondcolumn entry, and so on up until $2$ options for the thirdrow-thirdcolumn entry.  Applying rule of product yields a count.